# Remove left padding for a WPF ListBoxItem with GroupStyle defined for its ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I have a WPF ListBox with several headings. I acheived this by having a GroupStyle in which I define how each header will look:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource MyGroups}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- my header stuff -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>

    <!-- ListBox.ItemTemplate.. not shown -->
</ListBox>
```

Somehow, this causes the individual ListBoxItems to be slightly "indented" under their respective headers (Removing the GroupStyle removes the indentation, along with all the headers though).

I sort of see why they would want them indented by default, but is there anyway to remove that small left padding? I have tried to define a style for ListBoxItem to set the Padding = 0, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: can you set the padding in the GroupStyle?

Comment: Mmm I don't see a good place to set the padding in GroupStyle. I tried setting a style (with TargetType = ListBoxItem, and Padding=0) within GroupStyle.ContainerStyle, but obviously that led to a crash..

Comment: Can you set the GroupStyle in a resource, and then set the indent in the control? IIRC control level property definitions should always override resource level ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I could remove the indentation was to introduce my own control template for *GroupItem* in *GroupStyle.ContainerStyle*.

The template consists of two grid rows, one for the header, and one for the group items.

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding MyHeaderText}"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had some success negating the `ItemsPresenter` margins:

```
<ListBox>
...
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-5,0,0,0"></Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

But it's not exactly elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Put in a left margin of -20 then at (+)20 for the listbox item. Do either of those affect the outcome?

If so adjust to proper size as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer, kentoh! Just want to add that if you need to display custom template in a group header then you might want to use something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter 
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
        />
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: You could also just put an empty `<ContentPresenter />` in the template and things would automatically get wired up. Just as you use `<ItemsPresenter />`.

Answer (score -1):

A Lawrence Parker gave a valid solution in 2008 on